# What does Memory allocation mean?

Tags: linux, memory, out-of-memory

I use Linux Mint 21.2 and my machine is Intel Core i-7 6700 3.4GHZ.

I wrote a prime test in Python, and I checked it with large numbers.

It is like many tests, a variation of little Fermat, so I do some modular exponentiation like `powmod(3, n-1, n)`.

I could testify that `n = k * 2^k+1` is prime for `k = 6679881`.
This is no surprise since it is already proven prime.
My test needed 124 hours for this number with 2.010.852 digits.

Now I wanted to check the Fermat number, F_33, which is `n = 2^(2^k)+1` with `k = 33`.
This number has ~2.500.000 digits.

If I run it, after some minutes, I get the following error:

```
NU MP: Cannot allocate memory (size=549755818000)
bash: line 1: 19354 Aborted 
(core dumped)
```

Do I have a chance to run this test?

Comment: F_33 has ~ 2.59 billion digits, not just a few million.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use 512GB of RAM. Either you optimize your program or you rent a server.

I don't think swap could help you.

Comment: Yeah I'm not quite intimate with prime test algorithms, but I don't see why they'd need much RAM. Something that indicates you're using the wrong algorithm for the job.

Comment: Swap would allow execution to continue, but it would probably be far too slow.

Comment: Allocating this much swap would be nerve-wracking. In theory it could work depending on use patterns. If the app reads/writes randomly over the entire space, it will never finish. If it uses blocks which are smaller than the amount of physical RAM, it may actually finish but it will take ages. I won't dare to find out, I have SSDs with a limited life span.

Comment: It should be one large linear write and two interleaved reads, though not sure whether forward or backwards. This should work well on SSD but still a lot slower than in RAM.

Comment: @sinabala It's just a large powermod.

Comment: @Lereu You shouldn't need this much memory for a value of `n` that needs about 1 GiB. Where does your `powmod()` come from? Is it naive `a**b % c`?

Comment: @JoachimWagner No, it's gmpy2.powmod. But I check numbers with ~1.000.000 digits and more

Comment: @Lereu: Give the built-in `pow()` a try. Runs fine on my Python 3.9 system, though I didn't wait for a result. (Also, you keep dropping 3 zeroes. It's billions of digits, not millions.)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much impossible that you would live to see the result, even if you could continue; you can't, because what this error is telling you is that you ran out of ram.

Why I say you won't ever see the end:

Let's compare complexities:

> n = k * 2^k+1 is prime for k = 6679881

6,679,881 is roughly 2²³ (in fact, that's a safe upper bound) so your n≈2<sup>2²³+ 6679881</sup>≈2<sup>2²³</sup>

> n = 2^(2^k)+1 with k = 33

Let's divide that by the rough magnitude of your previous n to get a feeling for how many times later this problem is.

2<sup>2³³</sup> / 2<sup>2²³</sup> = 2<sup>2³³-2²³</sup> ≈ 2<sup>2³³</sup>

In other words, your larger n is so much more complicated to check for primeness that the hour you wait off do irrelevant compared to the exponent of your new problem, it doesn't even appear.